# Meaning of "she has hern" in Faulkner's 'As I Lay Dying'

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, etymology, literature, southern-white-vernacular-english

I am reading "As I Lay Dying" and have usually been able to look up the meaning behind the choice of words that Faulkner uses. However, I am unable to find a satisfactory definition of the word "hern" in the following quote:

> On the way home Cora is still singing. “I am bounding toward my God and
> my reward,” she sings, sitting on the wagon, the shawl around her shoulders
> and the umbrella open over her, though it is not raining.
> “She has hern,” I say. “Wherever she went, she has her reward in being
> free of Anse Bundren.”

The sample sentence is more of a clause, and is: "she has hern".

I am unable to find a satisfactory definition of this word in the [Faulkner Glossary](https://www.oprah.com/oprahsbookclub/the-faulkner-glossary-a-through-z/all) or in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hern) or in the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hern). The two top definitions simply refer to it as an archaic form of "heron", while the pronoun definition in Collins dictionary refers to it as a nonstandard form of "hers". Then in this instance, the narrator (the husband Tull) would be referring to his wife as saying that "She has hers", which would be idiomatic, and hard to state confidently as the correct interpretation. If this idiom is actually correct, then can someone explain what is meant by the word (and by extension the idiom)?

Attached are pictures from two editions of the book for broader context:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Compare _ourn_ in the next paragraph.

Comment: Her own=hern and ourn=our own. https://www.oprah.com/oprahsbookclub/the-faulkner-glossary-a-through-z/all